# show theres exactly one probability measure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\left(\Omega_i, \mathcal{P}(\Omega_i),\mathbb{P}_i \right), i \in \mathbb{N}$ be discrete probability spaces,
so that $\Omega_i$ die
$i$ are pairwise disjoint. Furthermore, let $\left(\pi_1,\pi_2,...\right)$ be a discrete probability density i.e. $\left (\pi_i \geq 0, i \in \mathbb{N} \text { and } \sum _{i \in \mathbb{N}} \pi_i=1\right)$. Show it
exactly one probability measure $\mathbb{P}$  on $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega)\right)$ with $\Omega := \uplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \Omega_i $ for all $A \subset \Omega_n$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ applies.

$\mathbb{P}(A):=\pi_n \mathbb{P}_n(A)$

In particular applies to everyone $B \subset \Omega$

$\mathbb{P}(B|\Omega_n)=\mathbb{P}_n(B \bigcap \Omega_n)$.

my problem: i dont know how to show that there exists exactly one probability measure

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\mathbb P(\Omega_n)=\pi_n$ for each $n$. Hence, $\mathbb P(B)=\sum_n \mathbb P(B\cap\Omega_n)=\sum_n \mathbb P(B|\Omega_n) \mathbb P(\Omega_n)=\sum_n P_n(B\cap \Omega_n)\pi_n$. So $\mathbb P(B)$ is uniquely determined by the given conditions.

Comment: Ok and why do you know $\mathbb P(\Omega_n)=\pi_n$ for each $n$.  ?

Comment: and i think i have to show too that P(A) is a probability measure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure the first condition i showed but not the second. can someone show me ?

Comment: @thombirdy $P(\Omega_n)=\pi_n $ is immediate  from  thedefinition. Take $A=\Omega_n$ and note that $P_n(\Omega_n)=1$. To show that $P$ os countable additive use the formula for $P(B)$ in my answer and use the fact that we can always interchange sums when the terms are non-negative: $\sum_n\sum_na_{nm}=\sum_m\sum_n a_{nm}$.